# How to access Spring Security Principal data within Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-security, thymeleaf

Within a Thymeleaf template, I want to access properties of the `Principal` implementation. The principal is set as intended into the `Authentication` object and composed as follows:

```java
public class ApplicationUser implements Principal {

    private Long userId;
    private String displayName;

    //...
}
```

```java
public class ApplicationUserDetails extends ApplicationUser implements UserDetails {

    //...
}
```

Within the application itself I could request the `Authentication` object, get the `Principal` and then cast the principal to `ApplicationUser`, to obtain desired properties like this:

```java
String displayName = ((ApplicationUser) authentication.getPrincipal()).getDisplayName();
```

My question now is, how can I obtain this data from the authentication object in a Thymeleaf template to use it e.g. to build a profile link?

I would like to get the following non working link example working with the displayName as tail:

```java
<a th:href="|/users/${#authentication?.principal.getDisplayName()}|">Profile</a>
```

What I would like to avoid is to add the required data to each view already within the controller, because I'd have to do that for each endpoint, since the profile link is located in the header.

**Many thanks for any help**

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are doing great!
Use the **#authentication object**, but you need to cast it to the appropriate class to access  desired properties. Here's how you can modify your link example to access the displayName property(GENERATE PROFILE LINK):

```
 <a th:href="|/users/${#authentication?.principal.displayName}|">Profile</a>
```

**NOTE:**
Make sure you have the appropriate Thymeleaf security namespace declaration at the beginning of your template to use thIS OBJECT:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
```

I HOPE IT WORKS!!!

Comment: Your version unfortunetely didn't work. Anyhow, I played along a little further, and it seems, that there is some casting going on under the hood when you try to access the properties by their fields directly as you did in your example. So this following solution works: `<a th:href="|/users/${#authentication?.principal.displayName}|">Profile</a>`. Maybe you wanna update your answer, then I can mark it as solved? Many thanks, and hope your'e doing great as well ;)

Comment: This isn't working for me. What is the means that the custom user details object is being casted so that thymeleaf can access the properties on the custom user details object? Is this happening automatically, or is there something in your code example that is facilitating this?

Comment: I discovered my issue. It seems the UserDetails.User is properly casted to the custom user details obejct by thymeleaf. I was populating the security context in a different area of the app with a plain UserDetails.User object.